# GWT - how to organize project to have multiple web pages and navigation between them

Tags: java, html, ajax, gwt, jakarta-ee

I'm a newbie to GWT (by the way being really impressed by it) and find it really attractive to  a person like me with good knowledge of C++/.NET desktop technologies willing to write web applications.

I started my own project based on the generated sample from the GWT Eclipse Wizard. This project generates simple html page with panels and main module java class (with onModuleLoaded) simply creates widgets and embedd it to the page. Now my question is - how to organize the code/project to have multiple html pages and navigation between then. For instance, main html page has a login form and a login button. If credentials are provided and login button pressed, the GWT service is executed on server and browser is navigated to the 2nd html page. Are there any more sophisticated sample applications available of such scenarios?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GWT is designed to reuse the same html page. This video is really helpful understanding the whole architecture: [GWT Best Practices](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM)

Also take a look to this tutorial for more complex examples: [MVP Architecture](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking so and now my thoughts are acknowledged.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the ["GWT / GAE Best Practices Project"](http://borglin.net/gwt-project/) blog and David Chandler's blog [TurboManage](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/).

Some keywords for a well structured GWT app:

- [gwt-presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/)
- [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/)
- [google-guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)
- [google-gin](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the very good [GWT Applications](http://www.gwtapps.com/) that comes with real cases examples. The sources are available for free. If you need deeper explanations of the concepts, you should buy the book. The sources are built with GWT 1.5 though.

Comment: Dead link unfortunately