# GWT need to know how to connect to.. or go from one page to another

Tags: gwt

im new to GWT ive been working on it since recently..

i want to know how can i go from "entry point page" ie,ImageViewer.java..
ive been suggested to create the memory by calling constructor on a perticular button

```
Button button = new Button("New button");
 button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
 {
  new LookupMaster(); //this is a composite
 }
 });
```

but this is not working.. i guess v can only call or get alert messages using this type..

can some one help me.

Comment: Take a look to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280074/gwt-how-to-organize-project-to-have-multiple-web-pages-and-navigation-between-t/2280145#2280145

Comment: Yep, you definitely should look at MVP. Other than that - the code above won't do a thing, since you *have to* add the Widget to a `Panel` (like `VerticalPanel`) for it to be visible. Otherwise it won't do a thing - the GWT compiler will probably even remove that code, since it doesn't do a thing from its perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to answer, since I have the feeling you're not understanding the basic concepts totally, but that's just my interpretation.

GWT is one html page that via JavaScript methods changes the content of that one page. When you want to display 'another' page you need to do this via methods that update the html dynamically. Since you are just starting with GWT, you might want to read this page on [Build User Interfaces](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUi.html) to understand the concepts and look at some examples provided with GWT.